# How to remove NA values from my file?

Tags: r

this is my r programming...

```
rowmean<-function(x,narm=TRUE){
 nr<-nrow(x)
 means<-numeric(nr)
 for(i in 1:nr){
  means[i]<-mean(x[i,],na.rm=narm)
 }
 means
}
rowmean(airquality,TRUE)
```

NA are not removes from my answers??

Comment: Just use `rowMeans`?

Comment: Either way, `mean` accepts only vectors, while `x[i,]` is a `data.frame`. Convert `means[i]<-mean(x[i,],na.rm=narm)` to `means[i]<-mean(unlist(x[i,]),na.rm=narm)`, for example